# Alternative tracking algorithms to Centroid?

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, python

I am using Centroid to track objects in a computer vision application I am working on.
But I am wondering if there are any other/better solutions to tracking objects than using Centroid? To me, it seems that this may be the most used algorithm?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Given that you tagged tensorflow, I was a little confused about the issue. Do you just need to follow an object after identifying it in the image?

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid Yeah, that is correct. If an object is detected in one image and it shows up in another image then I want the system to understand that it may be the same object, hence, tracking it.  But, you are right, I will remove the Tensorflow tag.

Comment: Well, to get started, it might be a good idea to check out these methods: KCF
CSRT
TLD
Boosting
MedianFlow
MIL
MOSSE
and
...

But I think this may not be the answer to your question @Araw